# Вывод символов

Tags: c++

Проблема в том что я хочу вывести на экран символ £ я узнал его код `char c = '£';`
`cout<<(int)c;` но когда я пытаюсь вывести на экран этот символ `£ char ch = 63; cout<<ch;` на экран выводит  другой символ

Comment: Если устроят мнемоники, то: &pound; или &#163;

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего ваша программа и ОС используют разные кодировки. Системная дефолтная ANSI кодировка покрывает весь набор символов ASCII, но использует другой механизм кодирования. Использование дефолтной кодировки не рекомендуется, так как на разных системах может быть использован разный дефолтный codepage. См. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1).
Вам необходимо явно задать кодировку в ваше программе См. [setlocale()](http://lord-n.narod.ru/download/books/walla/programming/Spr_po_C/16/setlocale.htm):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en-US.UTF-8");
```

Код фунта в UTF-8:

```
0xA3
```

Answer (score 2):

[@Роман1](/users/18838/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD1), видимо у Вас винда и кодировка [cp1251](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp1251) (в стандартном окошке cmd кодировка cp866 и там Вы бы увидели русскую букву 'г').

Да, там коду 163 (он же 0xa3) соответствует изображение не фунта, а чего-то похожего на `J`.

--

Кстати, в тексте вопроса Вы выводите код 63, а это символ '?'.

И пожалуйста, в следующий раз поподробней описывайте окружение, в котором программируете (хотя бы  ОС указывайте).